# Python, can't get results using Xpath of Chrome when scraping titles on this website

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I learned some simple skills to scrap websites and wanted to apply them to a very small project. Here I want to get every title of all the listed results from this [website](https://www.hotel.info/Search?lng=EN&LACCode=L172544%7CTHA&hs_f_locationnr=172544&hs_destination=Bangkok%20Metropolitan%20Region%2C%20Thailand&HotelMasterID=&ChainID=&hs_arrival=&hs_departure=&h_persons_total=1&hs_rooms=1&hs_roomType=2&cpn=5&location=Bangkok%20Metropolitan%20Region%2C%20Thailand&searchboxDateArrival=&searchboxDateDeparture=&searchboxNumber=1&searchboxPersons=1). I believe I gave the right Xpaths and I am able to get other text information (like the text before searching box). But I got '[]' blank results each time when I tried to scrap information in the body container (I tried many kinds of Xpaths too, so I think the problem is less likely to be caused by this) .

```
result = requests.get("https://www.hotel.info/Search?lng=EN&LACCode=L172544%7CTHA&hs_f_locationnr=172544&hs_destination=Bangkok+Metropolitan+Region%2C+Thailand&HotelMasterID=&ChainID=&hs_arrival=&hs_departure=&h_persons_total=1&hs_rooms=1&hs_roomType=2&cpn=5&location=Bangkok+Metropolitan+Region%2C+Thailand", allow_redirects=False)
selector = etree.HTML(result.text)
result.status_code
  200
title1 = selector.xpath('.//*[@id="L132761"]/@title')
print(title1)
  []
title2 = selector.xpath('.//*[@id="L132761"]/@title/text()')
print(title2)
  []
title3 = selector.xpath('.//*[@id="L132761"]/@href')
print(title3)
  []
```

The screenshot of DevTool on Chrome is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqllB.png). So for this first item I want to get is "Pullman Bangkok Hotel G".

I guess it's because this part is not "pure" text? I cannot select these words by mouse on the website. But I don't have any idea of how to scrap this kind of information. And after I click the title and go to its website, I was able to scrap the text inside this child link.

New Edit: The "result.text[:1000]" returns results starts with:
`'\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="EN"><![endif]-->\r\n<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9" lang="EN"><![endif]-->\r\n<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->\r\n<!--<![endif]-->\r\n<head>\r\n\t<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\r\n\t<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />\r\n\t<title>HOTEL INFO | Hotels Bangkok Metropolitan Region, Thailand</title>\r\n\t<meta charset="utf-8" /><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});`  So is it the case that this part is generated by javascript?

I hope I've explain the issue clear. Please tell me how to solve this problem or give me any suggestion you can think of.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get` gets plain html.

I believe the content you are trying to access is generated by javascript, which requests doesn't execute.

You could verify it by printing `result.text` and seeing what `requests.get` is returning.

If that's the case you may try using something like Selenium.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I can print out the text results... So is this the case? Anyway I'm learning Selenium now. Hope I can figure this out soon.

Comment: The "result.text[:1000]" returns results starts with: '\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="EN"><![endif]-->\r\n<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9" lang="EN"><![endif]-->\r\n<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->\r\n<!--<![endif]-->\r\n<head>\r\n\t<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\r\n\t<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />\r\n\t<title>HOTEL INFO | Hotels Bangkok Metropolitan Region, Thailand</title>\r\n\t<meta charset="utf-8" /><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});

Comment: @KeWang Your last comment would better be an edit to your question.